# Android SetBackgroundResource & SetBackground not working pre lollipop

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio, setbackground

I am developing my app using a Lollipop based avd where I was using SetBackgroundResource to set the background of a listview row using a custom drawable (layer-list). It works perfectly fine.

The LinearLayout xml row has a default defined background of blue.

Jelly Bean and Kit Kat, using SetBackgroundResource removes the default blue but it doesn't set it to the background drawable requested. I also tried SetBackground after altering minsdk from 15 to 16.

Still no joy.

```
((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_purple);
```

I have also tried;

```
((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.border_orange));
```

Row xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/border_blue"
android:padding="12dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:id="@+id/layout_row">
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_light"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2px"
    android:background="#D3DFE3" />
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_byline"
    android:text=""
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried this:
`((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_purple));`

Comment: I tried context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_blue) which produces error int cannot be applied to drawable and  getResources without context produces error cannot resolve method.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it is working but it removed padding from the LinearLayout therefore, it seemed as it hadn't worked. I believe it also removed padding from the Layer-list as well.

Comment: its not working in my case ...  used both  sideline1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray_connector);       sideline1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_connector));